# Does Universal clipboard works on ethernet?

Tags: wifi, copy-paste, ethernet, continuity

I have a mac mini 2018 connected to the same router/network, but using ethernet cable, and iOS device, connected to the same router/network, but using wifi.

But i can't use universal clipboard to paste text from ios to mac and vice versa. Should i connect my mac mini to the same network via wifi only in order to get it work?

Comment: How would it process Ethernet data protocol ?

Comment: It's connected to a same router, within same network.

Comment: It's not just connecting to the same network, there's other requirements.  Are you following all those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to turn off / on handoff on ios (or restart it), then it worked. So it works even without wifi on the mac, you only need to have bluetooth on and being connected to the same router.